# how to record a couple of animations in blender?

Tags: animation

I figured out how to record an animation in one timeline, but how do I save it and start recording another one?

Comment: You need to learn about Blender's NLA editor. A good introduction from CGDive is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAo7HxxxA08) but there are many other videos online.

Answer (score 0):

Open Dope sheet in Action Editor mode:

[image]

Mark the current action to be saved using this shield icon:

[image]

Then press duplicate icon to get the new action based on current one. Delete or modify keyframes.

[image]

Don't forget to press shield icon, overwise action will not be saved, if it is not active.

[image]

Repeat this steps to get full list of animations for your character.

In case of exporting FBX, I recommend open NLA editor and put all actions inside it side by side like this:

[image]

Then in export dialog, uncheck All actions and check NLA strips:

[image]

This will save only necessary animations with proper names.